# Update AppEngine with new content

Tags: google-app-engine

To update or deploy your code to AppEngine, I just use the command:

```
appcfg.py update <my_app_name>
```

That seems to work fine, but if I made any change and try to redeploy, it does not to override with the new code.  This begs the question:

What am I doing wrong?
How can I delete existing files that were previously uploaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost certainly changed the major version ID of your app, but not set it as the default version. Go into the admin console for your app (on appengine.google.com), and set the new version as the default in the 'versions' panel.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't change the version ID, but I still didn't see the new version until several minutes after "Closing update: new version is ready to start serving." I kept reloading and refreshing, and finally created a stackoverflow account and wrote a detailed message describing the problem, which I've now deleted/edited. Only then did it start working. Should Google change the message to "Closing update: new version will start serving in a few minutes"?

Comment: Try clearing your cache and/or refreshing the browser.  I generally get a 500 then the updated site is up and running.